# Duplicate Route Warning/Error in Clustered Environment

Tags: nats.io

I would like have multiple seed servers in a cluster so that when a single seed server goes down the whole discovery network would not go out of reach and new server would still be able to start up. However, the console shows the following error

> [8180] 2020/08/05 11:16:27.071803 [[32mINF[0m] 127.0.0.1:50890 -
> rid:3 - Router connection closed: Duplicate Route [8180] 2020/08/05
> 11:16:27.072794 [[32mINF[0m] 127.0.0.1:50891 - rid:4 - Router
> connection closed: Client Closed

I am not sure if that line indicates to a problem or if that can be ignored. My configuration is as follows:

```
nats-server.exe -p 8081 --cluster nats://localhost:7071 // Independent Seed 1
nats-server.exe -p 8082 --cluster nats://localhost:7072 // Independent Seed 2
nats-server.exe -p 8083 --cluster nats://localhost:7073 // Independent Seed 3

nats-server.exe -p 9091 --cluster nats://localhost:9091 --routes nats://localhost:7071,nats://localhost:7072,nats://localhost:7073 // Node 1
nats-server.exe -p 9092 --cluster nats://localhost:9092 --routes nats://localhost:7071,nats://localhost:7072,nats://localhost:7073 // Node 1
```

How can I avoid duplicate routes? Any changes needed to the configuration (still requiring multiple seed servers)?